# how insert same record in multiple times using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How to insert same record in multiple times without using for loop because its taking to much time I want to insert 10lack record at a time

```
              for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                List<student> students = new List<student>
                 {
                   new Student{student_id = i,Name= "new"}
                 };
                db.Set<Student>().AddRange(students);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

This above code taking to much time to inserting 10lack record.is it possible to insert same Name with different student_id multiple times without using for loop?

Comment: Student_id is different according to your code then, how you are saying you are inserting the same record ??

Comment: yes u'r right  but I need same name with different student_id is it possible without using for loop?

Comment: then according to me the loop is only the option.., you can improve your code by using `SaveChanges()` outside the loop area and declare the `List<Student>` before the loop. using this approach you can improve the performance of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move db code out of the loop:

```cs
//Declare the list object here
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    students.Add(new Student{student_id = i,Name= "new"});
}

db.Set<Student>().AddRange(students);
db.SaveChanges(); //Save changes to DB
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try calling SaveChanges() after the loop?
Also I recommend making the student ID an auto generated key and adding each student with an add directly to the set instead of an addrange with a list.